# Version conflict - Uncaught DOMException, the name "mwc-icon" has already been used with this registry. Custom Component

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html, lit

I'm trying to use Material Custom Component and also using some other components. But I have version conflict **Uncaught DOMException**.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mwc-icon" has already been used with this registry.

Currently, I'm using the yarn package manager to handle **custom-component** versions.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code, you're trying to register the same custom element more than once. Maybe you're importing a library twice?